# how change user account inactive as default (codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code CodeIgniter

I want help with the problem ,

**"I want to set the account as inactive by default "** it's active when a user creates new account.

```
<?php // status ?>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3<?php echo form_error('status') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <?php echo form_label(lang('users input status'), '', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <div>
        <label style="font-weight:500">
            <?php echo form_radio(array('class'=>'radio', 'type'=>'radio', 'name'=>'status', 'id'=>'radio-status-1', 'value'=>'1', 'checked'=>(( ! isset($user['status']) OR (isset($user['status']) && (int)$user['status'] == 1) OR $user['id'] == 1) ? 'checked' : FALSE))); ?>
            <span><?php echo lang('admin input active'); ?></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <?php if ( ! $user['id'] OR $user['id'] > 1) : ?>
    <div>
        <label style="font-weight:500">
            <?php echo form_radio(array('class'=>'radio', 'type'=>'radio', 'name'=>'status', 'id'=>'radio-status-2', 'value'=>'0', 'checked'=>((isset($user['status']) && (int)$user['status'] == 0) ? 'checked' : FALSE))); ?>
            <span><?php echo lang('admin input inactive'); ?></span>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Let me give you some explanation on this:**

If I understand you correctly you want to have every visitor as `inactive`, and (new) registered users as `active`? Which will become active when `$user` is set?

Am I correct, by reading your code, `<?php if ( ! $user['id'] OR $user['id'] > 1) : ?>` this part should show a line of code if it's a user? Currently you are saying two things:

The line of code needs to be shown if:

1. There is NO `$user['id']` known
2. OR if $user['id'] is higher than value 1.

So, lets say:

- Your code is showing to ALL users currently (both inactive and active).

You could fix it with something like this:

```
<?php if ( $user['id'] > 1) : ?>
        <div>
            <label style="font-weight:500">
                <?php echo form_radio(array('class'=>'radio', 'type'=>'radio', 'name'=>'status', 'id'=>'radio-status-2', 'value'=>'0', 'checked'=>((isset($user['status']) && (int)$user['status'] == 0) ? 'checked' : FALSE))); ?>
                <span><?php echo lang('admin input inactive'); ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

By deleting your `OR` statement it will now ONLY show to active users. If you wish to show a line of code to inactive users you could simply do this:

```
  <?php if ( $user['id'] > 1) : ?>
    <div>
        <label style="font-weight:500">
            <?php echo form_radio(array('class'=>'radio', 'type'=>'radio', 'name'=>'status', 'id'=>'radio-status-2', 'value'=>'0', 'checked'=>((isset($user['status']) && (int)$user['status'] == 0) ? 'checked' : FALSE))); ?>
            <span><?php echo lang('admin input inactive'); ?></span>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php else :?>
    // Code which is showing when there is NO $user['id'] known or lower than 2.
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this helped you.